# Getting the first point's coordinates of column with type path

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, path, column

I have the table above

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.geometry
(
    id          serial not null primary key,
    distance    float not null,
    height      float not null,
    coordinates path not null,
    gtype       geometrytype not null
);
```

trying to make a query like:

```sql
SELECT e.id, e.distance, e.height, e.coordinates, e.gtype
FROM rf.geometry e
WHERE coordinates[0][0] > 10;
```

I got the error:

> ERROR:  cannot subscript type path because it is not an array

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly, but as a workaround you can create an array from the path and access it as an array like this:

```
select (string_to_array(replace(right(left(p::text, -1),-1),'),(',');('),';'))[1] 
from (
    select path'[(0,1),(1,0),(5,0)]' as p
) f;
```

Above query returns (0,1) as text.  To return a point, use the following:

```
select point((string_to_array(replace(right(left(p::text, -1),-1),'),(',');('),';'))[1]) 
from (
    select path'[(0,1),(1,0),(5,0)]' as p
) f;
```