# Problem by using PostgreSQL type PATH with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sql

I have a PostgreSQL table below with a field `coordinates` of type path:

```
CREATE TABLE geometry
    (
        id serial not null primary key,
        coordinates path not null
    );
```

And I am trying to handle this table with the following python class below:

```
class Geometry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'geometry'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('geometry_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    coordinates = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

Trying to add a Geometry into the table:

```
session.add(Geometry(id = 1, coordinates = "path('(15.234428926980286, 47.95865145177352)')"))
```

I am getting this error:

> invalid input syntax for type path: "path('(15.234428926980286,
>   47.95865145177352)')

Comment: Check the representation from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html. An example of an open path syntax also in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351812/how-to-get-the-first-points-coordinates-of-a-column-with-type-path. Path with one point is for sure not valid as a closed path but maybe it is as an open path.

Comment: also the syntax is either `path '((15.234428926980286, 47.95865145177352))'` or `'((15.234428926980286, 47.95865145177352))'::PATH` - but both are invalid as *closed* path

Comment: A path with one point is an open path and needs to be wrapped in brackets [ instead of parenthesis (